# Always display specified number of decimal places in PHP (rounding up)

Tags: php, rounding

I need to display a floating point number with a specified number of decimal places (rounding up), specifically up to two decimal places even though the number has no fractional part. One way that I know is by using the `sprintf()` PHP function as follows.

```
echo sprintf("%0.2f", 123);
```

It returns `123.00`.

```
echo sprintf("%0.2f", 123.4555);
```

returns `123.46` but the following doesn't return what I need.

```
echo sprintf("%0.2f", 123.455);  // 5 is removed - the right-most digit.
```

I expect it to return `123.46` but it doesn't. It returns `123.45`. Although it's not a huge difference, I somehow need to return `123.46` in both of the cases.

---

The `round()` function can do it. `echo round(123.455, 2);` and `echo round(123.4555, 2);` return `123.46` in both the cases but I can't think of using this function because if the fractional part is not present, it displays no decimal digits at all. like `echo round(123, 2);` gives `123` and I need `123.00`.

Is there a function in PHP to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
number_format(123.455, 2, '.', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sprintf('%0.02f',round(123.455,2))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.